# NXP/Freescale kinetis-design-studio_3.2.0-1_amd64.deb

Tags: deb

I am trying to install kinetis-design-studio_3.2.0-1_amd64.deb from NXP/Freescale on UBUNTU 16.04. The installation stops with the following:

```
> sudo dpkg -i  kinetis-design-studio_3.2.0-1_amd64.deb

(Reading database ... 419128 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack kinetis-design-studio_3.2.0-1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking kinetis-design-studio (3.2.0) over (3.2.0) ...
Setting up kinetis-design-studio (3.2.0) ...

**********************************************************************
* Warning: This package includes the GCC ARM Embedded toolchain,     *
*          which is built for 32-bit hosts. If you are using a       *
*          64-bit system, you may need to install additional         *
*          packages before building software with these tools.       *
*                                                                    *
*          For more details see:                                     *
*          - KDS_Users_Guide.pdf:"Installing Kinetis Design Studio". *
*          - The Kinetis Design Studio release notes.                *
**********************************************************************
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160701-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
>
```

Comment: Do you have a direct link for the file `kinetis-design-studio_3.2.0-1_amd64.deb`?

Comment: I don't see Any error here. please complete the question

Comment: It just stops the installation, it would be  a free development  tool for ARM   microprocessors if it would work. It can be downloaded from NXP website, but NXP requires to know the e-mail of the down-loader.